# Cassandra metric TotalDiskSpaceUsed: does it include replication factor?

Tags: cassandra

As per Cassandra documentation about the [TotalDiskSpaceUsed metric](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/metrics.html):

> Total disk space used by SSTables belonging to this table, including obsolete ones waiting to be GC’d.

What is this "disk space used" exactly? Is it the physical space with replication already applied?

Let's assume, on a given node, the table contains 1GB of data before replication. The replication factor is 3. Should this value show 3GB?

Answer (score 2):

That should include the RF data - whatever is stored in the sstables, which includes replicated data.